# I want to find an optimal solution.... plz help!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, solution-verification, optimal-control

I want to ask a question about how to find an optimal solution.

Here are my equations:

\begin{align}
&GB_2 + GB_3 + GB_4 + \cdots + GB_r = 0 \nonumber \\ 
&GB_1 + GB_3 + GB_4 +  \cdots + GB_r = 0 \nonumber \\ 
&GB_1 + GB_2 + GB_4 +  \cdots + GB_r = 0 \nonumber \\ 
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \vdots \nonumber \\
&GB_1 + GB_2 + GB_3 +  \cdots + GB_{r-1} = 0 \nonumber  
\end{align}
where $G\in \mathbf{R}^{1 \times 2}$ is a unknown constant matrix, and $B_1, B_2, \cdots, B_r$ are constant matrices as follows:
\begin{align}
B_1 = B_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -0.1395 \end{bmatrix} , B_2 = B_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -0.0395 \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}

First, I have approached this problem by arranging the above equations into a state-space form.  However, I don't know how to figure out the optimal solution of $G$. Is there a way to find the optimal solution? 
Thank you so much.

Comment: I dont understand the system of equations. What is $B_r$? Do you mean all possible combinations of length $r-1$ will be equal to $0$? That only works when all $GB_s$ are equal and due to the fact that the sum is $0$, that means $GB_s=0$ holds for all $s$

Comment: It's my mistake. The constant value r = 4, in other words, GB_r = GB_4. I mistook my notation.

Comment: Let $G=\begin{bmatrix}g_1 & g_2\end{bmatrix}$. Take the first equation minus the second one: $G(B_2-B_1)=0$. It gives $g_2=0$. You cannot find $g_1$ as all $B_i$ are zeros at the first position.